# Find a Value and return the NEXT value in the same row with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have sets of data where "Material" and a corresponding number (in the same row) always appear. However, they won't always appear in the same cell.

What I am looking for is a VBA-script that will:

1. find the expression "Material", then
2. look for the corresponding number (the next value in the same row, not necessarily the neighboring cell), then
3. Copy+Paste the number in a certain cell.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Uni YaMo

Answer (score 0):

Im running out of time, but i hope the following snippet gets you started:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myCol As Long
Dim Val As Variant
Dim FoundMatCodes() As Variant

For intRow = 1 To 100
    On Error Resume Next
    MatCol = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Rows(intRow).Find(What:="Material", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
             SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

    ' found 'Material'
    If MatCol > 0 Then

        Dim r As Range
        Dim c As Range

        Set r = Rows(intRow)

        ' you may want to look at more cells
        For intCells = 1 To 10

            Set c = r.Cells(intCells)
            If (Not IsEmpty(c)) Then
                Debug.Print c.Value

                ' found numeric value
                If IsNumeric(c) Then

                    ' check if the array is already initialised
                    ' if not initialise with space for one element
                    If (Not FoundMatCodes) = -1 Then
                        ReDim FoundMatCodes(0)
                    ' array already been initialised, so initialise it 
                    ' with one more element than before, but
                    ' keep all previously added values
                    Else
                        ReDim Preserve FoundMatCodes(UBound(FoundMatCodes) + 1)
                    End If
                    ' just add the found value
                    FoundMatCodes(UBound(FoundMatCodes)) = c.Value
                    Exit For
                End If

            End If

        Next intCells

    End If

    MatCol = -1
Next intRow

' output to sheet Tabelle2
Worksheets("Tabelle2").Range("A1:A" + CStr(UBound(FoundMatCodes) + 1)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(FoundMatCodes)
End Sub
```

It looks for 'Material' in column a. If found it searches in the row for a numeric value. The first value found is stored in an array. After the loop the content of the array gets pasted into sheet 'Tabelle2'. Hope that helps.

Regarding the question about transpose, please have a look at:
http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Transpose-Function.html

Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am gonna try it out :-)

Comment: Dear #GinSonic 

I used the code and it worked. That's a good thing.. Thanks again!

as a beginner I feel the urge to ask:

1) what is happening within the "If IsNumeric(c) Then" condition? I can't follow it :/

2) when getting to pasting the value ("output") - can you explain the Transpose?

Thank you for your patience :)

Comment: this is great. comments rock :) that's also what the professor always said ;-)